# How to read different data types as user input in R?

Tags: r

Hi I am new to R programming and trying to read different data types as user input. I tried the scan() as follows

```
print("Arithmetic Operations")
print("a.Addition \t b.subtraction \t c.division \t d.multiplication")
print("enter two values and your choice ")
input <- scan()
```

But it shows the following error
Error in scan() : scan() expected 'a real', got 'a'

Can anyone suggest how to rectify this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As from the error you got, you should enter only numbers (`a real`) after calling the `scan` function. I think that you made a mistake by typing `a`, which is a  letter and not a number (*read the error message you got!*). And given that you want only two numbers, it would likely be better to specify the argument `nmax`, something like `input <- scan(nmax=2)`, so that `scan` will stop after reading two numbers.

Comment: @Kamgang I understood the error message but I want to read 2 numbers and a character together. Is it possible in R ?

Comment: I think that it will not allow you to read a character but there is an alternative way using the function `winDialogString`, but this works only under Windows. Check it out if you are working on Windows and if you do not understand how to use it for your example, you can drop another comment and I will explain how to use/adapt it to your problem.